# Determining the Equation of a Plane When Given a Point in the Plane and a Vector Normal to It?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I'm having trouble understanding how to create plane equations. Say I need to find the equation of a plane that contains the point (1,2,3) and is normal to the line $\vec{L}(t)=\left \langle 3t,1-t,0 \right \rangle$. How do I find the equation of the plane?

Comment: HINT: Given any two points in the plane $\mathbf{x}_1,\mathbf{x}_2$, we always have 
$$(\mathbf{x}_1-\mathbf{x}_2)\boldsymbol{\cdot}\mathbf{L}=0$$

Comment: Thanks, I figured it out.